# PCI-E with mPCI-E Sandisk won't boot

Tags: linux, hardware, boot

Configuring a 'new to me' Dell R610 with 6 15K SAS drives, each set paired up into a RAID 1 and then a Sandisk 256GB mPCI-E

http://www.ebay.com/itm/SanDisk-SSD-X100-256GB-Mini-PCI-E-mSATA-SOLID-STATE-DRIVE-SD5SF2-256G-1014E-/261724478033?pt=US_Solid_State_Drives&hash=item3ceffe9a51

configured using an adapter card

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Q00434-WBTUO-LT304-PCI-E-SATA-3-0-MSATA-High-Speed-Transmission-Desktop-Dedica-/261757794591?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cf1faf91f

I setup the 3 RAID 1 disks during installation to be `/`, `/home/`, `/usr/` and `swap`. The SSD I setup to be `/var/` All goes well with installation, but when booting it never seems to launch grub to boot. CentOS sees the SSD as `/dev/sda` but I installed grub to `/dev/sdb1`.

I tried using both Ubuntu and CentOS, finally I pulled the SSD out and powered it up and it brought up the grub rescue prompt. Am I making a mistake trying to put the `/var/` directory on the PCI-E SSD? Do I need to load drivers somewhere to get it to see it during boot? Just seems odd that it works find during install, and then fails to boot.

Any help is appreciated.